# android release package has error 'packageInfo is null'

Tags: android, build, release, capacitor

I create android project with capacitor 5.

I build debug package with `./gradlew assembleDebug`, the app-debug.apk is work.

But when I build release package with `./gradlew assembleRelease`, the apk-release-unsiged.apk was build success, but there is "packageInfo is null" when I install on phone.

Build using `npx cap build android` also have this error.

How to compile an Android app using the command line